# Where does the file get saved using "File file = new file(filename)" in Android

Tags: android, file

I am writing an android application. In the **MainActivity.java**, I created a method to write and then read contents from a file. These code runs successfully I and can store the data in a file named abc.txt, but I cannot find the written file in ES File Explorer.

```
public void writeInIt(View view) {


        try {
            String Message = editText.getText().toString();
            final File myFile = new File("abc.txt");
            if (!myFile.exists()) {myFile.createNewFile(); }

            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(myFile);

            outputStream.write(Message.getBytes());
            outputStream.close();

            editText.setText("");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


}
```

Where does it save the file? Why I can't I search it through the File Explorer?
Ref to "http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html", if i include path, it will definitely store in that path location. However, if I not locate the dir, it can still store in device, but where does the file actually save???

Comment: It doesn't save anything, it creates a `File` object. You need to write the file if you want to save it.

Comment: Oh I can save and read , but I hvnt locate the directory. And I know it saves successfully. But I cannot find it in my android device. Do I need the root privilege for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "File file = new file(filename)"

this code does not save anything, it only cretes a class wrapper for file or director path. The closest method to actually create file would be to use `file.createNewFile` method.

There is guide for writing files from google: [Saving Files](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html)

[edit]

following code generates exception "open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)":

```
    File fl = new File("test12.txt");
    try {
      fl.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: umm... it is just a part of my code.I can save and read successfully , but I hvn't locate the directory.. But I cannot find it in my android device. Do I need the root privilege for it? And I am ask for the location of the file but not how to save lol

Comment: @Question-erXDD if `filname` does not include any path, then your file is probably not being created. See my edited answer.

Comment: sorry for my poor presentation. I edited my question and add the whole function

Comment: @Question-erXDD check logcat for exception

Comment: anyway thz, run well in yr method

Answer (score 1):

```
 In Android manifest:

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

this is the code :

public void generateNoteOnSD(String sFileName, String sBody){
try
{
    File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),  "Notes");
    if (!root.exists()) {
        root.mkdirs();
    }
    File gpxfile = new File(root, sFileName);
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(gpxfile);
    writer.append(sBody);
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
catch(IOException e)
{
     e.printStackTrace();
     importError = e.getMessage();
     iError();
}
```

}

Comment: sorry for my poor presentation. I edited my question and add the whole function

Answer (score -1):

[image]

You can find this file in device manager.
Click your device (file symbol)
/data/user/0/com.example.myapplication/files and than follow this path

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).